# Where to connect the heat sink / body of SPX29300 voltage regulator?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, ldo

I have gone through the datasheet of [SPX29300](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810271506_MaxLinear-SPX29302T5-L-TR_C9013.pdf) and did not find anything related to the body / heatsink connection. I know that most of the heat sinks are connected to ground. However, what confuses me is that at the end of the document (where the dimensions are provided), the heatsink is labeled as "E-PIN". Is it enable pin? I'm using the enable pin, which is controlled by a microcontroller. I do not have this LDO in my hand. So I can not test it using multimeter. I'm placing it in PCB and so kind of worried what to do. Will I connect it to ground?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such cases always check [the most recent datasheet](https://assets.maxlinear.com/web/documents/spx29300_spx29301_spx29302.pdf) provided by the manufacturer because the ones you can find on datasheet databases could be old enough not to be relied on.

At p.4 it's indicated that the TAB is shorted to GND.
[image]

> the heat sing is labeled as "E-PIN". Is it enable pin?

No. The dimensions are shown as letters, and you should refer to the table on the next page for actual numbers for any dimension.